# Disable splash screen on Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

How to disable this splash screen when starting Office applications such as Excel?

[image]

Note:

- `/q` does not seem to work, `/nologo` idem, `/splash` idem
- `/e` disables the splash screen but does not open an empty spreadsheet as usual
- I have disabled the checkbox *File > Options > General > Start up options > Show the Start screen when this application starts*, but it does not remove the *splash* screen, it **only removes** the new start screen with recently opened files:

  [image]

Comment: Maybe restart after unchecking the last option. I have had 0ffice 365 for some years and no screen like that once set up.

Comment: @John Unchecking the last option just removes this screen on start up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlW7R.png. It doesn't remove the splash screen.

Comment: Perhaps do a full uninstall of Office 365, restart, install again, restart and test.

Comment: Already done @John. Note: it's not 365, but 2016.

Comment: Office 2106 turned into 365.  If reinstall did not work, you may need to do a Repair Install (Media Creation Link) or back up and reinstall Windows.

Comment: @John I don't have 365, but I still have the 2016 license, so I'm using this one.